# java using this in generic method (inheritance)

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, generic-programming

I'm trying to get access to child class methods and fields, when creating lambda, which is used in parent class. Code explains it more easily:

```
class Parent {
    List<Processor<? extends Parent>> processors;

    private void doSmth() {
        for (Processor<? extends Parent> processor : processors) {
            processor.doJob(this);  //this lines gives compile error
        }
    }

    public void registerListeners(Processor<? extends Parent> ... subscribers) {
        this.subscriberList = Arrays.asList(subscribers);
    }
}
```

Where `Processor` is a `FunctionalInterface`.

```
public interface Processor<T extends Parent> extends BiFunction<T, Message,  Boolean> {
    AtomicReference<Boolean> ok = new AtomicReference<>(false);

    default void doJob(T client, Message message) {
        if (apply(client, message))
            ok.set(true);
    }

    default boolean isDone() {
        return ok.get();
    }
}
```

The example of wanted usage of these classes:

```
Child childInstance= new Child(); //where Child class extends Parent
childInstance.registerListeners((child, message) -> child.callSomeChildMethod());
childInstance.doSmth(message);
```

It would be really cool to create lambda without redundant specifying of parameter type like in this line:

```
childInstance.registerListeners((Processor<Child>) (child, message) -> child.callSomeChildMethod());
```

(because it always should be type for which I register the listeners)
The problem is that code doesn't compile with error
`incompatible types: Parent cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Parent`
Which is quite logical (I understand the reason). Is there some way in java I can get this code working?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to always include the complete error message - and point out the line it comes from. And: compilers do not **throw**. Terminology is important, be precise about each and any character you write down!

Comment: @ghostc updated

Comment: What is your intention behind `processor.doJob(this, ...);` ? It is not valid java code.

Comment: @curlyBraces to show that there are more arguments, but this is probably not relevant to the question, removed it

Comment: Can you mention other places where you have used `List<Processor<? extends Parent>> processors;` inside `class Parent`?

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran updated question. Basically, I register listeners, and then doSmth(message) method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of having `List<Processor<? extends Parent>> processors;` in `Parent` class is not suggestible. As you see, since you have not mentioned the type of processes the list has; wherever you call `processor.doJob(anyObjectHere)` an error gets thrown, one way or the other(unless you do explicit cast)

Try doing something like this;

1. Declare a `Client` instead of your `Parent` which holds the type of processors in `List<Processor<? extends Parent>> processors`;

   ```
   abstract class Client<T extends Client<T>> {
       List<Processor<T>> processors;

       public void doSmth(Message message) {
           for (Processor<T> processor : processors) {
               processor.doJob(getThis(), message);  
           }
       }

       abstract T getThis();

       public void registerListeners(Processor<T> subscribers) {
           this.processors = Arrays.asList(subscribers);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change your `Processor` definition to incorporating `Client` rather that `Parent`

   ```
   interface Processor<T extends Client<T>> extends BiFunction<T, Message,  Boolean> {
       AtomicReference<Boolean> ok = new AtomicReference<>(false);

       default void doJob(T client, Message message) {
           if (apply(client, message))
               ok.set(true);
       }

       default boolean isDone() {
           return ok.get();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now you can create your `Child` like this;

   ```
   class Child extends Client<Child> {
       boolean callSomeChildMethod() {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       Child getThis() {
           return this;
       }
   }
   ```
4. And call them the same way you did before;

   ```
       Child childInstance= new Child(); //where Child class extends Parent
       childInstance.registerListeners((child, message) -> child.callSomeChildMethod());
       childInstance.doSmth(message);
   ```

This way you have neither compile errors nor warnings

Comment: this way allows to avoid  both compiler warnings and specifying lambda type parameter, so marked as an answer, thanks a lot! I've seen construction like Client<T extends Client<T>> many times in the code, gonna sort it out for myself this time)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply cast the `processor` object to declare that you want to pass it an object of a class derived from `Parent` (it could be `Child`), and cast `this` to the same type. It can even be generic:

```
private <T extends Parent> void doSmth() {
    for (Processor<? extends Parent> p : processors) {
        Processor<T> processor = (Processor<T>) p; // explicit cast
        processor.doJob((T) this);  //no compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is, that processors actually are Processor<Child> type, so this cast will throw an exception

Comment: @A.Porvakov: Please see my Edit